# Trying to build a .csv file in php from an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to convert the following array into a .csv file where the questions will be on the first row and the corresponding answers in the second row and at the beginning a Timestamp should be there along with the time.

I have tried in the following way:

```
<?php

  $qna = [
    [
      "questionNo"=> 1,
      "question"=> "I am the life of the party.",
      "answer"=> 2
    ],
    [
      "questionNo"=> 2,
      "question"=> "I feel little concern for others.",
      "answer"=> 4
    ],
    [
      "questionNo"=> 3,
      "question"=> "I am always prepared.",
      "answer"=> 2
    ],
    [
      "questionNo"=> 4,
      "question"=> "I get stressed out easily.",
      "answer"=> 4
    ]
  ];
  
  $csv = '/home/ankur/Desktop/iq_data.csv';
  $fp = fopen( $csv , 'w' );
  $questionarray = array();
  $answerarray = array();
  $keyarray = array();
  $valuearray = array();
  foreach( $qna as $key => $questions) {
   
   $questionarray[]  = $questions['question'];
   $answerarray[]    = $questions['answer'];
  }
  $keyarray[] = "Timestamp";
  $valuearray[] = time();
  
  $row = array();
  array_push($row,$keyarray);
  array_push($row,$valuearray);
  array_push($row,$questionarray);
  array_push($row,$answerarray);
  
  for($i=0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row[$i] );
  }
  
  fclose( $fp );
  
?>
```

It is creating the .csv file but the timestamp and its value is not in the same row as that of the question answer as follows:

```
Timestamp           
1676484864          
I am the life of the party. I feel little concern for others.   I am always prepared.   I get stressed out easily.
2   4   2   4
```

I want that the Timestamp column to be in the same row as that of the questions as follows:

```
Timestamp     I find it hard to imitate the behavior of other people.     My behavior is usually an expression of my true inner feelings, attitudes, and beliefs. 
12/3/21 14:05   TRUE    TRUE
```

Kindly suggest if possible where am I doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Help me to understand why your code doesn't simply look like this: https://3v4l.org/2Rt7Z or do you want https://3v4l.org/W65N0 ?  I don't know where `TRUE` is coming from.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake , I wrote it incorrectly, The order should be like this `Timestamp    | I am the life of the party.  | I feel little concern for others.        
1676484864   |       2                                |                    4
`

Comment: Please do not offer question details as comments.  Please [edit] your question whenever you wish to improve it.

Comment: You want it like this? https://3v4l.org/1eejp  maybe simpler code like this? https://3v4l.org/BXqAJ

Answer (score 0):

You only need two lines to be inserted in your csv file, so you only need to loop the `$qna` array to populate two flat arrays.

You can prepopulate the first element of the first array with the static word "Timestamp" and the first element of the second array with the current unix time.

Then you loop over the `$qna` array to push questions and answers into their respective arrays.  I am using a body-less loop, but you can perform the pushes into the array inside of a foreach loop's body if you like.

When finished populating the two arrrays, use `fputcsv()` to properly write to your csv file.

```
$csv = '/home/ankur/Desktop/iq_data.csv';
$fp = fopen($csv, 'w');

$header = ['Timestamp'];
$answers = [time()];
foreach ($qna as ['question' => $header[], 'answer' => $answers[]);

fputcsv($fp, $header);
fputcsv($fp, $answers);
fclose($fp);
```